# Add if statement to a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an audio file play on my html page (I can get it to play using onclick). But, I am trying to play an audio clip when a specific text is displayed. For instance, I am trying to play an audio clip that needs to be specific to the displayed text (or whatever object).

So, I have some strings (Questions and Answers) but I can't figure out what to assign to the strings to trigger the audio file to play. Also, maybe there's another way by just making a function for each question.

Comment: Are you sure you're not asking about JavaScript instead of Java? If so please tag accordingly. But I'm sure you're not talking about JavaHelp (please read the description of the tags when you use them)

Comment: By the way, regardless of what language you're talking about, you don't assign the audio to a string. You should abstract the concept of "text that can be displayed and has audio associated to it" to its own structure or class, that could have as members the text to display (as a string) and the audio.

Comment: Ahh, I am talking about javascript. Thank you for making that clear. Ok, right now I have a const string of questions just separated by commas. Is that what you mean?

Is there a way for me to assign more attributes to the strings of questions?

Comment: What you're asking is not discernible to me. Please edit or re-ask your question to be more clear.

Comment: Use an array of objects. Each object can have the question, answers, and the URL of the audio clip. When you click on the text, it plays the corresponding clip.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you Barmar. That will get me on the right track. I just need to figure out how to add the audio clip url to the corresponding correct question/answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please append your code, what you've tried, and the current / expected output (if applicable). Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

1. Place your audio source as strings in an array, coupled with other info, ( you mentioned questions );
2. Iterate the array and build the DOM nodes, placing an event listener on click or any other event you want to trigger the sound;
3. Just add the audio source to the html audio node dinamically when the event occurs and play it;

```js
const data = [{
  question: "What's the name of Culham?",
  choices: ["Alan", "Alastair"],
  answer: "Alastair",
  audio: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Alastair_Culham_voice.ogg"
}, {
  question: "What's the name of Thompson?",
  choices: ["Bill", "John"],
  answer: "Bill",
  audio: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Bill_Thompson_speaking.ogg"
}]


const generate = () => {
  
  root.innerHTML = ""
  audio.src=""
  
  const idx = Math.round(Math.random() * (data.length - 1))
  root.innerHTML += `<div>${data[idx].question}</div>`
  data[idx].choices.forEach(c => {
    const btn = document.createElement("button")
    btn.innerText = c
    btn.onclick = function() {
      if (data[idx].answer === c) {
        audio.src = data[idx].audio
        audio.play()
        audio.onended = generate
      } else alert("Wrong Answer, try again")
    }
    root.appendChild(btn)
  })
}

generate()

reset.onclick = generate
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<audio id="audio"></audio>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: So instead if "onclick" is there something that would allow for "OnDisplay" or "when chosen"? For instance, my current code selects a question at random from my list. So, I wanted that random question to play a specific sound. But I can't do onclick because that won't do what I have in mind.

Comment: Just to reiterate my goal.

1. User Clicks "start button"
2. Random question displays and also an audio Que to play the specific audio file aloud.
3. Answer to question is selected by user.
4. Correct answer is displayed
5. Next button is selected by user for next question and steps are repeated.

Comment: @BrandonLindsay OnClick only executes when the button is clicked, that should achieve your goal.

Comment: There is no such "onchosen" event :-) but you can easily implement it. I updated the example, with random generated indexes and a sort of question/ multiple choices answers logic. Hope it clarifies further.

Comment: @CesarePolonara is it allowed to review shared github post? They really help when trying to learn.

Comment: You should include all relevant code into your question, since every question and answers on SO are meant to become a reference for future visitors. External references might have broken links in future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your questions in one place and the audio cues in another. Keep them together in data objects that have properties per question. For example:

```
questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is your quest?',
    answer: 'To seek the holy grail.',
    badAnswers: [
      '16.9 Gigawatts',
      'African or European?',
      'Red. No, blue!'
    ],
    audioQuestion: 'hmm.mp3',
    audioCorrect: 'youtu.be/0D7hFHfLEyk',
    audioIncorrect: 'sproing.mp3'
  },
  {
    question: 'My milkshake brings more boys to the _____.',
    answer: 'yard',
    badAnswers: [
      'stand',
      'steps',
      'park',
      '21st century'
    ],
    audioQuestion: 'hmm.mp3',
    audioCorrect: 'youtu.be/i4YutyVP7ig',
    audioIncorrect: 'sproing.mp3'
  }
]
```

And then you can have a function that knows what to do when given an element of this array.